# Store Always Encrypted column values in EF Plus Core Audit

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, always-encrypted, entity-framework-plus

I'm currently using Always Encrypted to encrypt specific columns on TableA.
I added Audit logs using Entity Framework Plus Core but it's logging the added properties of Table A unencrypted.
Is there a way I can store the encrypted values in the Audit logs table?

Answer (score 0):

No, it cannot.

The Audit feature from EF Plus (https://entityframework-plus.net/ef-core-audit) takes values directly from the ChangeTracker. Therefore, it doesn't know about database value that's encrypted.

There is no way to do it with this feature.